# Genetic algorithm for optimization function

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

Please help me,
I try to implement GA in java to resolve minimize of summation of (Xi)^2 function that X value is double between [-100,100] , i = 1,2,3,...,30 and have 4 populations.
I can't get the correct result.
[Check Source Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GV4ptQT0EYrOGlH2j5qdPj5OWbFkhBNI)
Thanks you

GeneticAlgorithm.java

```
....
public Population evolvePopulation(Population population) { 
    Population newPopulation = new Population(population.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); ++i) {
        Individual firstIndividual = randomSelection(population);
        Individual secondIndividual = randomSelection(population);
        Individual newIndividual = crossover(firstIndividual, secondIndividual);
        newPopulation.saveIndividual(i, newIndividual);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newPopulation.size(); ++i) {
        mutate(newPopulation.getIndividual(i));
    }
    return newPopulation;
}
```

GeneticAlgorithm.java

```
public Individual randomSelection(Population population) {
    Population newPopulation = new Population(Constants.TOURNAMENT_SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.TOURNAMENT_SIZE; ++i) {
        int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random()*population.size());
        newPopulation.saveIndividual(i, population.getIndividual(randomIndex));
    }
    Individual fittestIndividual = newPopulation.getFittestIndividual();

    return fittestIndividual;
}
```

Population.java

```
...
public Population evolvePopulation(Population population) { 
    Population newPopulation = new Population(population.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); ++i) {
        Individual firstIndividual = randomSelection(population);
        Individual secondIndividual = randomSelection(population);
        Individual newIndividual = crossover(firstIndividual, secondIndividual);
        newPopulation.saveIndividual(i, newIndividual);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newPopulation.size(); ++i) {
        mutate(newPopulation.getIndividual(i));
    }
    return newPopulation;
}
...
```

Individual.java

```
public void generateIndividual() {
    df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.CHROMOSOME_LENGTH; i++) {
        String gen = df.format((randomGenerator.nextDouble()*(201))-100);
        double gene  = Double.parseDouble(gen);
        genes[i] = gene;
    }
}
```

Result:

Generation: 1 - fittest is: 187840.0388

Generation: 2 - fittest is: 145642.2474

Generation: 3 - fittest is: 143804.0066

Generation: 4 - fittest is: 164595.30819999994

Generation: 5 - fittest is: 192525.51659999997

Generation: 6 - fittest is: 176011.80959999998

Generation: 7 - fittest is: 165286.99679999996

Generation: 8 - fittest is: 181544.71279999998

Generation: 9 - fittest is: 180144.33559999996

Generation: 10 - fittest is: 178226.74199999994

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code here. Does it work?

Comment: Please include any necessary code in your question (as a [mcve]). A link to your google drive is not appropriate.

Comment: It work sir but i can't get a good result and it's not in order for all generations. Please kindly download my code on the link above sir

Comment: Please help me, I don't know what its wrong

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **genetic search** is not guaranteed to find an optimal solution in any *finite* amount of time, although it might converge very fast in its immediate neighborhood. Also, genetic exploration does not provide any mean to certify that a given solution is actually optimal, so it should be used only when a **good enough** solution is fine.

Looking at the code snippets you posted here on S.O., I would make the following observations:

- In `randomSelection()`, you randomly select a subset of the initial population, and then return the best individual among that group. My take on this is that you want to give a reproductive advantage to those individuals that, according to the fitness function, carry a better genome. Is that correct?
- In `evolvePopulation()`, you randomly select two parents, and then combine them with a **crossover** step. You then apply a random mutation to the resulting genome, and add it to the new population.

At this point I see the following issue: if both parents are randomly selected, there is absolutely no guarantee that the best individuals of your population actually get the chance to reproduce. I would instead select only one of the two parents randomly, so to ensure that every individual has at least one child.

It is also unclear to me, because it is not shown, whether `mutate()` does always change some part of the genome, or whether this is only done with a given, low, probability.

It is important to keep in mind that both `crossover()` and `mutate()` can have a **destructive** effect on your population: it is not written anywhere that the offspring resulting from applying these operators is *better* than the previous generation.

Thus, what you seem to be missing out is a `selection()` step. One should generate many more individuals than it intends to keep inside the new generation, and then kill off all the worst ones before letting them to reproduce again.

Moreover, if you don't want your search to temporarily degenerate, you should save the best individual (or the best first N individuals) across two subsequent generations.